initial and final topologies on $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$
Suppose $X=\{(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots) \in [0,1]^\mathbb{N}\mid a_n\neq 0 \:\text{for at most one} \: n\}.$ Now define the inclusion $\iota_n: [0,1] \to X: a \to a\cdot e_n,$ with $e_n=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ with the 1 at the the nth position. We also define the projection $p_n: X \to [0,1]: (a_0,a_1,\dots) \to a_n,$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in both the inclusions and the projections.
We now are given three topologies on this set: the initial topology $\tau_i$ for the projection, the final topology $\tau_f$ for the inclusion and the metric topology $\tau_m$. The last one is defined by the metric $$
d(a\cdot e_i, b \cdot e_j) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        |a-b| & \text{if}\: i=j, \\
        a+b & \text{if}\: i\neq j.
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
Now we are asked first show that for every topology defined, every $\iota_n$ is a homeomorfism on its image.
Then compare these topologies and lastly which are compact.
I am having some trouble with the first part. Let's start with the initial topology of which we know that the set $M=\{p_n^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{P}(X)\mid U \in \tau_{e}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ , with $\tau_{e}$ the euclidean topology on $[0,1]$, forms a subbasis for $\tau_i$. To get an idea of how the opens look we first want to go to a base. The elements of this subbase are of two forms. Suppose we have a $U \in \tau_e$, then if $0 \notin U$ the element is $p_n^{-1}(U)=(0,\dots,0,U,0,\dots)$ with the $U$ at the nth position. If $0\in U$ then $p_n^{-1}(U)=([0,1],\dots,[0,1],U,[0,1],\dots)$ with the $U$ at the nth position. Now we take finite intersections which simplify by watching how an intersection between two of these elements looks. From this I get that the elements from the base are either of the first form of our subbase or of the second form of our subbase but with a finite amount of positions which aren't $[0,1]$ instead of just one.
I think this should give me the tools to try and answer the first question for the initial topology. To show $\iota_n$ is a homeomorphism we need to show it's bijective(which is evident and doesn't depend on the topology) and that it's bicontinuous. The continuous  part is evident since the inverses of all base elements are open in $[0,1]$. But now I need to show that for a $U \in \tau_e:\iota_n(U) \in \tau_i$. When $0 \notin U$ it's evident, but I'm having trouble when $0 \in U$ since neither our base elements are of the form $\iota_n(U)=(0,\dots,0,U,0,\dots)$ with $0\in U$. I'm having a similar problem with the final topology(namely that singleton $\{0\}$ has to be open in [0,1]) but I'm thinking if I am able to solve this, then that part will also work out.
Did I do something wrong in defining my subbase and base? Any tips?

I guess instead of "If $0\in U$ then $p_n^{-1}(U)=([0,1],\dots,[0,1],U,[0,1],\dots)$ with the $U$ at the nth position" there should be "If $0\in U$ then $p_n^{-1}(U)=([0,1],\dots,[0,1],U,[0,1],\dots){\color{red}\cap \color{red}X}$ with the $U$ at the nth position".

that's what I meant, I had a bit of trouble with notation in general for this exercise.


When $0 \notin U$ it's evident, but I'm having trouble when $0 \in U$ since neither our base elements are of the form $\iota_n(U)=(0,\dots,0,U,0,\dots)$ with $0\in U$.

Recall that we have to show that for each natural $n$, the map $\iota_n$ is a homeomorphism onto the image $\iota_n([0,1])=\{(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots) \in [0,1]^\mathbb{N}\mid a_m=0:\text{for all natural } m\ne n\}$. So $\iota_n(U)=(0,\dots,0,U,0,\dots)=p_n^{-1}(U)\cap \iota_n([0,1])$ is open in $\iota_n([0,1])$.

The continuous part is evident since the inverses of all base elements are open in $[0,1]$.

Then the map is a homeomorphism onto the image, being a continuous bijective map from a compact space onto a Hausdorff space. This also implies that the map $\iota_n$ is a homeomorphism onto the image when $X$ is endowed with the topology $\tau_f$ or with the topology $\tau_m$.

which are compact.

The space $(X,\tau_m)$ is not compact, because it contains an infinite set $\{e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that the distance between each its distinct points is $2$. On the other hand, the space $(X,\tau_i)$ is compact, because for each open neighborhood $U$ of the point $(0,0,\dots,0)$
there exists a finite subset $F$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $X\setminus U$ is a closed subset of the finite union $\bigcup_{n\in F} \iota_n([0,1])$ of compact sets. Finally, I guess that $\tau_f$ is the finest topology on $X$ such that all maps $\iota_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$ are continuous. Then $\tau_f\supset \tau_m$, so the space $(X,\tau_f)$ is not compact too.

How do $\tau_m$ and $\tau_i$ compare I'm guessing $\tau_i \subset \tau_m$ because around every point in the base elements of $\tau_i$ we can make an open ball around that point contained in the open?
